# How to pass an event fd between two process in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, embedded-linux

I have two process, ProcessGUI and ProcessMaster. My both processes will do some action in some conditions. Suppose once some thing happens in Master process, GUI process has to display some thing. I want to indicate that by changing the event fd. Is there any way, where I can share an event fd between two process.

Comment: [Consider instead using a pipe.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) X happens in master, master writes X to pipe. GUI reads X from pipe and draws it on the screen.

Comment: Either ensure that the `eventfd`'s `CLOEXEC` flag isn't set when you fork (in which case it will be the same FD in the child process) or send it via [the `SCM_RIGHTS` ancillary message of a unix domain socket](http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix). (Note: this applies to most file descriptors in general)

Comment: @user4581301 Actually my data is very big. So I am putting it in shared memory. So I want to change just the event fd so that the other process can detect it. I got to know that event fd is lighter than message queue and made for inter process communication.

Comment: You don't have to send much data. In this case all you need to do is send a byte to wake the reader. I'm liking the possibilities of @ColonelThirtyTwo 's `SCM_RIGHTS` trick, though. Have to try that out myself.

Comment: I'd go (and I went, in some real-life cases) with @ColonelThirtyTwo approach: make one of the process the parent of the other - which make sense anyway since one is no use without the other - through forking, they will then be able to share file des' since "the child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file descriptors" (at the moment the fork is done). And BTW do not forget to close or dup/close the _others_ shared fd in the child. Did that (forgot to) too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to achieve what you want.

The first one that popped into my head is using `sendmsg` to share the eventfd over a socket.
That approach is feasible, but it requires both processes to open a socket.

One other approach is using signals. There are 2 signals that can be used as "User Signals"; USR1 & USR2, you can set up one process to catch a user signal, and the other to send it (`kill` it, to be more accurate).

The last thing I can think about is using a socket and (e)polling it. To be honest, it's just like the first approach, but without sharing the FD over the socket.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Linux signals to communicate the two processes. Here you have some examples: [Linux signals](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/).

One of your processes generates a signal with the raise() method and the other registers a signal handler to react the event with signal() function.

Comment: `raise` isn't sufficient to move a signal from one process to another.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can create a shared library with shared memory between both processes. So, the signal only indicates when something is changed. Then, you can access the shared data using mutex mechanisms.